# Mindray-BS200 cinnection with LIS error

Tags: c#, hl7-v2

When my LIS receive message with type ORU^R01 (contains the Sample result OBX,OBR) it respond s with ACK^R01 this cause the mindray bs-200 software to shutdown!!! I couldn't explain that since I followed the instructions in the manual, any help will be nice , thank you in advance

Comment: Could you add more details? Describe the hardware, show some code snippets etc.

Comment: the code is too long to put it but eventualy it recieve a hl7 message parse it and responds with ACK message like this :
 "MSH|^~\&|ilias|eCAC|||||ACK|3beaab72-280d-4213-bd4d-e5856f004d6f|P|2.3.1||||0||ASCII

MSA|AA|1"

the same response mentiened in the manual (https://fr.scribd.com/document/234555627/BS-200-Host-Interface-Manual-v1-2)  page 25-26, the weird thing is that the software doesn’t respond with an error message or something it shutdown imeadiatly
!!!!!! 
thanks for responding i appreciate that

Comment: i tried the message mentioned befor and this one "MSH|^~\&|ilias|eCAC|||||ACK^R01|39a2e0c9-3463-407b-a6f0-d1a3e6c7847b|P|2.3.1||||0||ASCII

MSA|AA|15|Message accepted|||0"

and this one causes thr shutdown when i changed the message type in the header  from ACK^R01 to ACK the mindray software didn't get the ACK and kept sending the same ORU^R01 message

Comment: Do you use NHapi to generate your message?

Comment: No , I didn't find any documentation about nhapi so i couldn't use it

Comment: I tried to send a HL7 message on mind ray bc20s and it shutdown too !!! I'm using parser in https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/HL7-version-2x-messaging-d429fbee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to have similar problem with this machine.
Mindray-BS200  requires you to send ACK message exactly as they put it in the documentation

here is a sample from the manual
MSH|^~\&|||Manufacturer|Model|20070719145307||ACK^R01|2|P|2.3.1||||0||ASCII||| 
MSA|AA|2|Message accepted|||0|

and this is yours
MSH|^~\&|ilias|eCAC|||||ACK|3beaab72-280d-4213-bd4d-e5856f004d6f|P|2.3.1||||0||ASCII
MSA|AA|1

so you have to add 3 component separator (|) bars at the end of ASCII
and also the MSA segment should say exactly "MSA|AA|2|Message accepted|||0|"

this time the machine would not crash. 
But still in my case it does get the acknowledgment but the request timeouts out.

Comment: If you find a solution for this don't forget to come back here.